# How do I make sure an array is made before all other code is ran?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

The problem I am having is that when I call .map on the array I am using it returns 'undefined', but when I log the contents of the array right before the .map call is made it says the array is not undefined.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var key = [];
    d3.xml("data.xml", function(error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;
        data = [].map.call(data.querySelectorAll("Names"), function(suspect) {
            return {
                name: suspect.querySelector("name").textContent
            }
        });
        for (var y = 0; y < data.length; y++) {
            key = Object.values(data[y]);
            LegendOptions[y] = key[0];
        };
    });

    var str1 = [null,null,null];
    var cntr = 0;
    d3.xml("data.xml", function(error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;
        data = [].map.call(data.querySelectorAll("element"), function(suspect) {
            return {
                axis: suspect.getAttribute("id"),
                value: +suspect.querySelector("value").textContent
            }
        });
        for (var y = 0; y < LegendOptions.length; y++) {
            str1 = [null,null,null]
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length/LegendOptions.length; i++) {
                str1[i] = data[cntr];
                cntr++;
            };
            d[y] = str1;
        };
    });
});
        var RadarChart = {
            draw: function(id, d, options){
                var cfg = {
                    radius: 5,
                    w: 600,
                    h: 600,
                    factor: 1,
                    factorLegend: .85,
                    levels: 3,
                    maxValue: 0,
                    radians: 2 * Math.PI,
                    opacityArea: 0.5,
                    ToRight: 5,
                    TranslateX: 80,
                    TranslateY: 30,
                    ExtraWidthX: 100,
                    ExtraWidthY: 100,
                    color: d3.scale.category10()
                };

                if('undefined' !== typeof options){
                    for(var i in options){
                        if('undefined' !== typeof options[i]){
                            cfg[i] = options[i];
                        }
                    }
                }
                cfg.maxValue = Math.max(cfg.maxValue, d3.max(d, function(i){return d3.max(i.map(function(o){return o.value;}))}));
                console.log(d);
                var allAxis = (d[0].map(function(i, j){return i.axis}));
```

The last line is where .map is being called and where I get the undefined error. Also, the array 'd' is being stored in a different document which is called later on in an html file.

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
            <title>Radar chart</title>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="RadarChart.js"></script>
    <style>
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica;
    }

    #chart {
        position: absolute;
        top: 200px;
        left: 100px;
    }   
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="body">
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label" id="langDiv"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</form>
</html>
```

RadarChart.js is the file throwing the error and where .map is being called.

Comment: so, `d` is an array ... but is `d[0]` and array?

Comment: also this line `d[y] = str1;` do you have a global var named `d`?

Comment: d is a global variable and d[0] is an array

Comment: so, `console.log(Array.isArray(d[0]))` where you have `console.log(d)` outputs `true`?

Comment: No it outputs false however as far as I can tell there is an array at d[0].

Comment: if it outputs false, then it isn't an Array - perhaps the asynchronous function `d3.xml("data.xml"` isn't complete before `RadarChart.draw` is called - put console.log's where `d` is being "built" and in `.draw` - watch the console to see what order things are running

Comment: Yes that is exactly what is happening. D3.xml is completing after .draw is being completed.

Comment: Or I guess in this case it is just draw

Comment: The problem is I don't know where to build 'd' in order for it to happen before the chart is drawn

Comment: How do I make sure that the array is populated before all the other code is run?

Comment: Hmmm ... how does the `d` in the document ready relate to the `d` in `RadarChart.draw`?

Comment: They are one and the same

Comment: well, no, because `d` an argument of `.draw` - I take it `.draw` is called with the "global"  `d` as the argument

Comment: Added an answer anyway :p

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to waiting for `d` to be populated is to use a Promise for the asynchronous loading

In the following, I combined the two `d3.xml()` because it seems to make sense to me!

```
var dataLoaded = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var tdata = [];
        var cntr = 0;
        d3.xml("data.xml", function(error, data) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
            //
            [].forEach.call(data.querySelectorAll("Names"), function(suspect) {
                return {
                    name: suspect.querySelector("name").textContent
                }
            }).forEach(function(item) {
                var key = Object.values(item);
                LegendOptions[y] = key[0];
            };
            //
            var tdata = [].map.call(data.querySelectorAll("element"), function(suspect) {
                return {
                    axis: suspect.getAttribute("id"),
                    value: +suspect.querySelector("value").textContent
                }
            });
            LegendOptions.forEach(function() {
                var str1 = [null, null, null];
                for (var i = 0; i < tdata.length / LegendOptions.length; i++) {
                    str1[i] = tdata[cntr];
                    cntr++;
                };
                d[y] = str1;
            });
            //
            resolve(d);
        });
    });
});
```

---

```
var RadarChart = {
    draw: function(id, d, options) {
        dataLoaded.then(function() {
            var cfg = {
                radius: 5,
                w: 600,
                h: 600,
                factor: 1,
                factorLegend: .85,
                levels: 3,
                maxValue: 0,
                radians: 2 * Math.PI,
                opacityArea: 0.5,
                ToRight: 5,
                TranslateX: 80,
                TranslateY: 30,
                ExtraWidthX: 100,
                ExtraWidthY: 100,
                color: d3.scale.category10()
            };

            if ('undefined' !== typeof options) {
                for (var i in options) {
                    if ('undefined' !== typeof options[i]) {
                        cfg[i] = options[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            cfg.maxValue = Math.max(cfg.maxValue, d3.max(d, function(i) {
                return d3.max(i.map(function(o) {
                    return o.value;
                }))
            }));
            console.log(d);
            var allAxis = (d[0].map(function(i, j) {
                return i.axis
            }));
            //... you didn't post any more than this
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I can not thank you enough. This problem has been troubling me for so long and it was so nice of you to take time out of your day to help me. With a little tinkering i was able to implement it completely.